# Sums of powers of two.. with one restriction.

Tags: combinatorics

For a positive integer $n,$ let $a_n$ denote the number of ways of representing $n$ as a sum of powers of 2, ***where each power of 2 appears at most three times***, and the order of the terms does not matter. For example, $a_8 = 5$ because of the representations
\begin{align*}
8 &= 8 \\
&= 4 + 4 \\
&= 4 + 2 + 2 \\
&= 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 \\
&= 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1.
\end{align*}(The representation $1 + 2 + 1 + 4$ is the same as $4 + 2 + 1 + 1.$) Compute $a_{1000}.$

Comment: I tried the normal method of counting powers of two, and then subtracting the bads.

Comment: If you take a look at the first several values... a very clear pattern emerges.  http://oeis.org/A008619  Try to prove that the recognized pattern is in fact correct for yourself.

Comment: oh thank you, but why is that true?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious and computed $a_n$ for $n=1,\ldots,8$, say? The pattern’s clear, and writing out the representations gives a clue as to why it holds.

Comment: Consider this... can you reason why $a_{103}=a_{102}$ and in general $a_{2k+1}=a_{2k}$?  Note... I'm not asking you to actually calculate the values of $a_{103}$ at the moment... I am just asking you to reason why whatever $a_{102}$ happens to be that $a_{103}$ needs to be the same.  (*Could you have used all three $1$'s in one of the arrangements counted by $a_{102}$?*)

Comment: yes i figured it out. However, why does it make that pattern?

Comment: If you are asking "why does it make that pattern" then you haven't "figured it out" yet.  My previous comment is trying to help guide you to actually understanding why it follows that pattern, if you'd pay attention.

Comment: @SAGNIKUPADHYAY delete your comment, you clearly don't understand the question.  We are trying to count the number of [restricted partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$ where partsize is restricted to powers of $2$ and each partsize is only allowed to be repeated up to three times each.

Comment: @JMoravitz In the question the words " at most" were used which means three or less . So we can use the terms once also if we want. And man no need to be rude i am still a student of class 9, it would be better if you could just point out where I did not understand the question man. Also I am deleting the answer and comment if you want so.

Comment: @SAGNIKUPADHYAY point out where you did not understand?  You appeared to be confusing $a_n$ with something having to do with the number of summands or maximum number of summands within in one of these representations, where again, we are wanting to count the number of distinct representations themselves.  That is... if we were to list the representations, we want the length of the list.  For $n=10$ that is: $6\text{ different representations}\begin{cases}8+2\\8+1+1\\4+4+2\\4+4+1+1\\4+2+2+2\\4+2+2+1+1\end{cases}$.  We could count them by listing them all out... or... we spot the pattern

Comment: To expand a bit on JMoravitz' hint. If $b_{2m}$ is the number of ways of writing $2m$ as a sum of $2,4,8,\ldots$ following the rules, then why do we have $b_{2m}=a_m$? And why $a_{2n+1}=b_{2n}+b_{2n-2}$? And so on :-)

Comment: If you are a compulsive generatingfunctionologist then you can also approach this as follows. Let $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3$. Find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product $f(x)f(x^2)f(x^4)f(x^8)\cdots$ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prove @Oldnboy's conjecture with a hint by @JyrkiLahtonen to a technique the OP might not know well. Restate $n=\sum_jc_j2^j$, with $0\le c_j\le3$, as $x^n=\prod_jx^{c_j2^j}$, so $a_n$ is the $x^n$ coefficient in$$\begin{align}\prod_{j\ge0}(1+x^{2^j}+x^{2\cdot2^j}+x^{3\cdot2^j})&=\prod_j\frac{1-x^{4\cdot2^j}}{1-x^{2^j}}\\&=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)}\\&=(1+x+x^2+\cdots)(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots).\end{align}$$This is just the number of integers from $0$ to $n$ inclusive with $n$'s parity, i.e. $\lfloor\tfrac{n}{2}\rfloor+1$ as claimed.

We can use this technique if $3$ is replaced with another Mersenne number. Otherwise, it's a bit tricky because the product doesn't telescope. I've asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816338/big-o-behaviour-of-sums-of-powers-of-2-partitions-with-restricted-repetition) about further generalization.

Comment: Telescopes for the win :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, OP asked for "computed" value of $a_{1000}$and nobody computes better than my Mac ;)

```
def countInternal(n, last1, last2, last3):
    # recursion will eventually finish here
    if n == 0:
        return 1

    # in the beginning we have to start with 1
    # otherwise we start with the last used number
    start = 1 if last1 == 0 else last1

    # if the last number is already used three times, just double it.
    if start == last2 and start == last3:
        start *= 2

    # here we accumulate the total number of combinations 
    # for various starting numbers
    s = 0

    # when starting number is bigger than n, we are done
    while start <= n:

        # recursive approach
        # we add a number of combinations starting with number start
        # start, last1, last2 are the last 3 used numbers
        s += countInternal(n - start, start, last1, last2)

        # after that, just double the starting number 
        # and do another round
        start *= 2
    return s

def count(n):
    result = countInternal(n, 0, 0, 0)
    print("a(" + str(n) + ")=" + str(result))
    return result

count(1)
count(2)
count(3)
count(8)
count(10)
count(1000)
```

The code prints:

```
a(1)=1
a(2)=2
a(3)=2
a(8)=5
a(10)=6
a(1000)=501
```

So the answer is 501. For the sake of curiosity I have computed a few other values:

```
a(10000)=5001
a(10001)=5001
a(20000)=10001
```

Therefore conjecture:

$$\boxed{a_n=\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor + 1}$$

Comment: I'm sure we've both found this code runs very slowly for large $n$. It's better to use the fairly obvious relations $a_{2n+1}=a_{2n}=a_n+a_{n-1}$. See my code [here](https://repl.it/repls/PreciousHuskyHexadecimal).

Comment: @J.G. I agree with you. But even your code is terribly slow compared to closed form solution :)

Comment: Very, very, ugly code.

Comment: @AlexWang: Beat this: def a(n): return n // 2 + 1

Comment: The "trivial" solution